# Ctrl+p vs window.print() results in different page design

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, printing

I show the printing page by JavaScript using `window.print()` but it shows different design when compared to `Ctrl + p` print dialog.

Any other way to implement `Ctrl + p` with same design as in `window.print()`?

Answer (score 1):

It was because of using the print from a tool-tip balloon which taking some space from the print display in print preview, below css solved the problem

```
@media print {
    .tooltipster-base.Balloon {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: this was actually also my case. I have a tooltip on icon button that triggered the `window.print()`. Hiding the tooltip completely on print, as you suggested, solved my issue